# How to declare a variable outside an if statement

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
last_state={}
last_device={}
last_substate={}
with open("TESTFILE.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        device = row[0]
        state = row[1]
        model = row[2]
        substate=row[3]
        #time = row[4]
        if device in row:

            if substate == 'Not joined' and model !='electric_meter':
                if state == "Offline":
                    N_off = [device]
                   # print N_off, reader.line_num

                if state == 'Online':
                    N_on = [device]

                if N_off == N_on:
                    print device, reader.line_num
```

I am trying to compare the device ID of these 2 loops so that I only use the the ones that meet all criteria. Im not sure why but I get this error:

```
      `if N_off == N_on:
NameError: name 'N_off' is not defined`
```

I am not very familiar with Python and how declaring variables works, but I tried to declare them globally and that gave me the same error. I understand it is because I am using `N_off` outside its scope, but I am not sure how to rectify that.

Comment: Declare it above `if device in row:`

Comment: how did you try to declare it globally?

Comment: That code of your, is it inside a function? Where have you declared `N_off` for the first time?

Comment: i tired to declare it after `if device in row` with `  N_off = None` and then i get the error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Declaring it in the spot @Rekesh suggested as well as removing the [ ] from N_off and N_on seemed to do the trick, although I cant say I understand the later. Either way thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want or need `N_off` to be global, you need to `import` the file that contains the global declaration of `N_off` and use it in this file as `filename.N_off`.  In the file containing the declaration, you do not need to prefix it with the file name.  Note that you do not (normally) need to declare variables in python.  Global variables are an exception.

**Example:**

***OtherFile***

```
global N_off
N_off = value
```

***CurrentFile***

```
import OtherFile
if OtherFile.N_off == N_on:
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this portion of your code:

```
if state == "Offline":
    N_off = [device]

if state == 'Online':
    N_on = [device]

if N_off == N_on:
    print device, reader.line_num
```

As you can see, `N_off` is only defined `if state == "Offline"`, and `N_on` is only defined `if state == 'Online'`.

So when you go to compare them in the last `if` statement, Python has only defined one of them, and therefore only knows one of them.

You simply have to initialize somewhere in your program in a way that assures that they are both defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `N_off` and `N_on` inside `if` statements and only one or the other can be true and execute, Try this:

```
last_state={}
last_device={}
last_substate={}
with open("TESTFILE.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        device = row[0]
        state = row[1]
        model = row[2]
        substate=row[3]
        #time = row[4]
        if device in row:

            if substate == 'Not joined' and model !='electric_meter':

                N_off = None
                N_on = None

                if state == "Offline":
                    N_off = [device]
                   # print N_off, reader.line_num

                if state == 'Online':
                    N_on = [device]

                if N_off == N_on:
                    print device, reader.line_num
```

However I don't see the logic in this:

```
if state == "Offline":
    N_off = [device]
    # print N_off, reader.line_num

if state == 'Online':
    N_on = [device]

if N_off == N_on:
    print device, reader.line_num
```

because this:

```
if N_off == N_on:
    print device, reader.line_num
```

Will never be executed since state cannot be both on and off at the same time.

Comment: A device repeats itself many times, the status can change from online to offline. What I am trying to execute with that line is if N_Off[device] == N_on[device] then print, I only want it to print when the devices are unstable. Is there another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to loop over all the devices and want to check if consecutive rows has value of same device as "Offline" and "Online".

you can use below code, basically while checking if variables are equal, I have added additional condition to check if variables are initialized. if they are not initialized, I assumed that your condition will not be satisfied.

```
last_state={}
last_device={}
last_substate={}
#reader = [('device','Offline','model','Not joined')]
# Instead of file reading from list
reader = [('device','Offline','model','Not joined'),('device','Online','model','Not joined')]

for row in reader:
    device = row[0]
    state = row[1]
    model = row[2]
    substate=row[3]
    #time = row[4]

    if device in row:

        if substate == 'Not joined' and model !='electric_meter':
            print(state)
            if state == "Offline":
                N_off = [device]


            if state == 'Online':
                N_on = [device]

   # added condition to check if this variables are initialized or not.
            if 'N_on' in locals() and 'N_off' in locals() and N_off == N_on:
                print "Check passed"
```